# Page to create object and sub object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, partial-views

I'm sure there have been tons of people asking this type of question but I can't quite figure out how to word it.

I will try to explain. I am working to model an ethernet network where devices have ip addresses. I've setup my entity framework models so that the ip and subnet are stored in a separate table to ensure uniqueness across the system.

I'd like the user to be able to create a device and its associated IP at the same time if the IP they want is not already in a dropdown list.

I setip a partial of the IP Address page RenderPartial on the device page and I get this error:

Here is the question, How do I fix this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `PcnWeb.Models.Device`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `PcnWeb.Models.IPAddress`.

Here are my models:

IP Address Model:

```
namespace PcnWeb.Models
{
    public class IPAddress
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int ipAddressRecId { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> ipOctet1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet3 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ipOctet4 { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> smOctet1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> smOctet2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> smOctet3 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> smOctet4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Device Model:

```
namespace PcnWeb.Models
{
    public class Device
    {
        [Key]
        public int deviceRecId { get; set; }

        public int ipAddressRecId { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(64)]
        [Unique]
        public string Name { get; set; }        

        [StringLength(256)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would have thought that it would be pretty easy to have the associated device creation page with an inline ipaddress creation page.

Here's the Device page:

```
@model PcnWeb.Models.Device

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create  a Device";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Device</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ipAddressRecId, "IPAddress")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ipAddressRecId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ipAddressRecId)
        </div>
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/IP_Address/_Create.cshtml");
        }

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, "Comment")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Here is the IP Address Partial:

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to include this

@model PcnWeb.Models.IPAddress

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>IPAddress</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ipOctet1, "ipOctet1")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ipOctet1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ipOctet1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ipOctet2, "ipOctet2")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ipOctet2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ipOctet2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ipOctet3, "ipOctet3")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ipOctet3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ipOctet3)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ipOctet4, "ipOctet4")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ipOctet4)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ipOctet4)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.smOctet1, "smOctet1")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.smOctet1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.smOctet1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.smOctet2, "smOctet2")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.smOctet2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.smOctet2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.smOctet3, "smOctet3")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.smOctet3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.smOctet3)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.smOctet4, "smOctet4")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.smOctet4)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.smOctet4)
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

So from all this, it looks great to me, the validation works client side. I'll have to write some javascript to hide the IP address partial unless they select new from the dropdown list.

Here is the question again, How do I fix this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `PcnWeb.Models.Device`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `PcnWeb.Models.IPAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

This errors means that there is mismatch between model type in your partial view and  type of model passed to this view. But as i can see you trying to render the partial view without model passing.
Your code example worked for me.

So, to solve this problem you can do the next steps.

1. Ensure that the view path is right;).
2. Try so 'send' model to your partial view explicity like

main view

```
@model PcnWeb.Models.Device
//some code here
@Html.Partial("path_to_view", Model)
```

partial view.

```
@model PcnWeb.Models.Device
@Html.DropdownListFor(x=>x.ipAddressRecId, YourDlistSource) //or anything you need
```

this works for me.

Alternatively if you need edit submodel in partial view you can do this

```
 @model PcnWeb.Models.Device
    //some code here
    @Html.Partial("path_to_view", Model.IPAddress)//pass the submodel to partial view
```

then your partial view must be with another type.

```
    @model PcnWeb.Models.IPAddress

    //some code here
```

Answer on comment. To resolve object reference exception try initialize your submodel in constructor.

```
public class Device
{
///properties
    public Device()
    {
        IPAddress = new IPAddress();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused when you say the example worked for you. Did you try to submit the form. I'll add the IP Address Partial view above.

Comment: When I try to do this ```@Html.Partial("path_to_view", Model.IPAddress)``` I get this error: ```Object reference not set to an instance of an object.``` do I have to do something fancy in the controller?